# ArrayList type java to make an array

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 ArrayList doscObject=[{id=21},{id=212}];
```

I want to get an array name IdArray that contains all the ids like in above example  output should be following:
    IdArray={21,212}
how can i do that?

Comment: That's not even valid Java. Start by learning the basic syntax, by reading a book.

Comment: `List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{21,212});`

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that you have an class `IdObj`:

```
public class IdObj {
   int id;
   public int getId();
}
```

and that `docsObjects` contain objects of type `IdObj`, then create the `ArrayList`
by iterating through `docsObject`: I used the `forEach` type of for loop:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (IDObj idObj in docsObject) {
       idList.add(idObj.getId()); 
    }
```

If docObjs is a HashMap of (value IdObj) you can iterate with:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (Map.Entry entry in docsObject.entrySet()) {
        IdObj idObj = entry.getValue();
        idList.add(idObj.getId()); 
    }
```

Comment: He showed a hashmap so maybe you should use `get(key)`

Comment: @texasbruce what he showed id weakly specified, I interpeted this as an ArrayList of an object which has an field id.

Comment: it's hashmap so i have to use get(key)

Comment: Then you have to search, or read how to iterate through a hashMap (using Entry Set Iterator), or keySe´t if you want only the ids

Comment: Update how to itertao over a (hash)map

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want a plain array and not an ArrayList.

```
int[] idList = IDObj[docsObject.size()];
for (int i=0;i<docsObject.size();i++)
{
    idList[i] = docsObject.get(i).getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make much sense but I'll give a brief primer for working between the two collection types...

Arrays:

```
int[] idArray = {21, 212};
```

ArrayLists:

```
List<Integer> doscObject = new ArrayList<Integer>();
doscObject.add(21);
doscObject.add(212);
```

ArrayLists -> Array:

```
Integer[] idArray = doscObject.toArray(new Integer[doscObject.size()]);
```

Array -> ArrayList:

```
Collections.addAll(doscObject, idArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a result array that is big enough to hold all the values in the original first (because array size is fixed and you need to declare before using), and copy each over to the new array:

```
int[] idArray = new int[doscObject.size()];
for(int i=0, max = doscObject.size(); i<max; i++){
    idArray[i] = ((Map)doscObject.get(i)).get("id");
}
```

It would be much easier if Java has a second order function for mapping array but it doesn't so you need to do it manually.

Comment: it says the method get(string) is undefined for the type object. and in the line 
idArray[i]=docsObject.get(i).get("id"); has red line under get("id");

Comment: and when i hover over it, it says Add cast to 'docsObject.ger(i)'. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @user1964901 If it is a raw object, you need to cast it to Map by adding the `(Map)` in the front.

Comment: thnks that is helpfull